# Pycharm cannot import GDAL from conda environment on another computer

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, gdal

I have created a Python 3.4 conda environment and install GDAL via conda-forge channel on both computers and works perfectly on one computer but not for the other computer, where it only works when activating from the command line. (The problem comes from transferring the pycharm project)

In both cases I always point to the corresponding project interpreter first, where all packages are shown including GDAL. However, although I can import the rest of the packages, `import gdal` on the second computer returns:

> File "C:\Users\burbujas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\osgeo__init__.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)`
>
> File "C:\Users\burbujas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)`
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

I don't remember which computer was used to initialize the project, probably the first one.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is something here. Although I cannot apply it.
https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/111

In more detail:
Re-declare the PATH in the Configuration-Section (Run/Debug-Configurations) where prefix is the PATH to the wanted conda-env:
prefix;prefix\Library\mingw-w64\bin;prefix\Library\usr\bin;prefix \Library\bin
(path's according to my win 7 machine, YMMV)
add GDAL_DATA pointing to prefix \Library\share\gdal

In PyCharm you can do that going to Settings. Then Project interpreter. Click on the arrow down and then show all. On the right the last option will be Show path for the interpreter. Add library/share/gdal

Comment: I tried the suggestion with project interpreter but unfortunately did not work. I created a new 3.5 environment and installed gdal again and it seems to work everywhere. I don't intend to investigate it further unless I have trouble again. Apparently, there is not many people with the same problem anyway...